# Expanding search bar exanding to the left and show search button

Tags: html, css

I am using following code and code work fine. but i wanna that when user click on search button then search button will also show like stackoverflow search bar has.

HTML :-

```
              <form>
                <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search..">
            </form>
```

CSS

```
input[type=text] {
display:block;
margin: 0 0 0 auto;
width: 250px;
box-sizing: border-box;
border: 2px solid #ccc;
border-radius: 4px;
font-size: 16px;
background-color: white;
background-image: url('/searchicon.png');
background-position: 10px 10px; 
background-repeat: no-repeat;
padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px;
-webkit-transition: width 0.4s ease-in-out;
transition: width 0.4s ease-in-out;

}

input[type=text]:focus {
width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: So what's the problem?

Comment: Try something yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow these steps

1. Create a `button`
2. Place that `button` on the search bar
3. set `display` property of that `button` to `none`
4. now whenever you focus on the search bar, change `display` property of that `button` to `block`

try implementing this code on your own first ...

```css
input[type=text] {
display:block;
margin: 0 0 0 auto;
width: 250px;
box-sizing: border-box;
border: 2px solid #ccc;
border-radius: 4px;
font-size: 16px;
background-color: white;
background-image: url('/searchicon.png');
background-position: 10px 10px; 
background-repeat: no-repeat;
padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px;
-webkit-transition: width 0.4s ease-in-out;
transition: width 0.4s ease-in-out;

}

input[type=text]:focus {
width: 90%;
}
input[type=text]:focus + .but{
  display: block;
}

.but{
  cursor:pointer;
  width: 100px; 
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  right:5px;
  top:5px;
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<form>
                <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search.."><input class="but" type="button" value = "search">
            </form>
```

Comment: @Unidan tell me what I can do to improve my answer. If it has satisfied your query then accepting it would be the best thing to do :)